# Scraping for Images, Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, image, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape for the images from a toy website and can't seem to figure out how. Please help. I'm using Nokogiri. Here's what I got so far:

```
webpage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
section = webpage.css('div.category-products')
item_container = section.css('div.container-fluid.product-list-container')
item_list = item_container.css('.item')
list = item_list.css('.product-label-wrap')
image = section2.css('.image-product-list')
```

Here's the html tag:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbQo9.png)

Comment: In your browser developer console you can right click on the element and "copy selector"

Answer (score 3):

You can get the element's attribute by using `attr`

```
image.css('img').attr('src')
```